# Numpy.unique - getting output with consistent depth

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have two numpy arrays of lists:

```
r = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[4,5]])
q= np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
```

and I use `numpy.unique` to trim them down to just the unique lists

```
np.unique(r)
array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]], dtype=object)
np.unique(q)
array([1, 2, 3])
```

You can see that the output from `np.unique(q)` has a different depth.

My question is; how can I keep a consistent "depth" for both of the above examples?

i.e. so that `np.unique(q)` gives:

```
array([[1, 2, 3]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the way `q` is constructed. When you say

```
q = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
```

You are creating an array of 6 items:

```
In [77]: q.size
Out[77]: 6
```

When you apply `np.unique` to this array, each of the 6 items is considered a separate value, and the unique ones are returned.

If instead you create a `q` with just 2 items which are Python lists:

```
In [78]: q = np.empty(2, dtype='object')

In [79]: q[:] = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

In [80]: q.size
Out[80]: 2
```

Then `np.unique` returns the desired result:

```
In [81]: np.unique(q)
Out[81]: array([[1, 2, 3]], dtype=object)
```

---

The difference is perhaps clearer if you start with a different `q`:

```
In [20]: q = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,4]])

In [21]: q2 = np.empty(2, dtype='object')

In [22]: q2[:] = [[1,2,3],[1,2,4]]

In [23]: q
Out[23]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 4]])

In [24]: q2
Out[24]: array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]], dtype=object)
```

These two arrays, `q` and `q2` look similar, but they behave differently.

`q` is an array of shape (2,3) with 6 values which are ints.

`q2` is an array of shape (2,) with 2 values which are Python lists.

When you apply `np.unique` to `q`, it is finding the unique values among the 6 ints.

When you apply `np.unique` to `q2`, it is finding the unique values among the 2 lists.

```
In [25]: np.unique(q)
Out[25]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [26]: np.unique(q2)
Out[26]: array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]], dtype=object)
```

Your alternative is really just making `np.unique(q)` 2-dimensional.

```
In [27]: np.array([np.unique(q).tolist()],dtype='object')
Out[27]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4]], dtype=object)
```

If that is what you want to do, then you could instead use `np.atleast_2d`:

```
In [28]: np.atleast_2d(np.unique(q))
Out[28]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

If you want the result to be

```
array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]], dtype=object)
```

then you have to construct `q` as a 2-element array of dtype `object`. Initializing it with

```
q = np.empty(2, dtype='object')
```

is the easiest way I know how to achieve this.

---

And if you find yourself dealing with NumPy arrays of dtype `object`, ask yourself it you might not be better off with plain Python objects:

```
In [32]: set(map(tuple, ([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]])))
Out[32]: {(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4)}

In [33]: %timeit set(map(tuple, ([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]])))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 µs per loop

In [34]: %timeit np.unique(q2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.1 µs per loop
```

Comment: I used this, based on your answer:  `np.array([np.unique(q).tolist()],dtype='object')`

Comment: Although this does still give a size of 3 not 1 as in your answer (`Out[81]`) - strange considering that the output looks identical.

Comment: What should the answer be if `q` were (as a list of lists) `[[1,2,3],[1,2,4]]`? Should the unique values be `[1,2,3,4]` or `[[1,2,3],[1,2,4]]`?

Comment: `[[1,2,3],[1,2,4]]` in that case

Comment: Then `np.array([np.unique(q).tolist()],dtype='object')` will not work for you. I've added some more discussion of this above.